# Scala refactoring

Tags: scala, refactoring, traits

I have the following class diagram and would like some help with refactoring.

[image]

The code:

```
trait id {
  val id: String
  def uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
}

abstract class node extends id {
  def deepCopy: node
  def hasSameId(n: node): Boolean = n.id == id
}

trait manifest {
  val properties = new mutable.HashMap[String, Any]
  val manifest: immutable.HashMap[String, (String, String)]
  def isComplete: Boolean
  def setProperty(k: String, v: Any): this.type
  def getProperty(k: String) = properties(k)
  def getAllProperties = properties
  def hasEqualProperties(p: mutable.HashMap[String, Any]): Boolean = {
    if (properties.size != p.size) false
    else {
      properties.map(prop => p(prop._1) == prop._2).foldLeft(true)((r, c) => r && c) // this will give trouble if off manifest property table have the same size but different optionals from an open manifest
    }
  }
}

trait sealedManifest extends manifest {

  def setProperty(k: String, v: Any) = {
    if (manifest.contains(k)) {
      val keyType = manifest(k)._1
      val valueType = v.getClass.getCanonicalName
      if (keyType == valueType) properties(k) = v
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(""" Expecting type "%s" received type "%s" for "%s" """.format(keyType,valueType,k))
    } // test for type as well
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException(""" "%s" is not on manifest""".format(k))
    this
  }
}

trait openManifest extends  manifest {

  def setProperty(k: String, v: Any) = {
    if (manifest.contains(k)) {
      val keyType = manifest(k)._1
      val valueType = v.getClass.getCanonicalName
      if (keyType == valueType) properties(k) = v
      else throw new IllegalArgumentException(""" Expecting type "%s" received type "%s" for "%s" """.format(keyType,valueType,k))
    } // test for type as well
    else properties(k) = v
    this
  }

}

case class system(val uid: String = null) extends node with openManifest {

  val id = if (uid != null) uid else uuid

  override val manifest = immutable.HashMap(
    "name" -> ("java.lang.String","req"),
    "description" -> ("java.lang.String","opt")
  )

  override def isComplete: Boolean = true

  def CONNECTS(s: system, id: String = null) = {
    new systemCONNECTSsystem(this, s, id)
  }

  def PRODUCES(d: dataset, id: String = null) = {
    new systemPRODUCESdataset(this, d, id)
  }

  def <= (kv: (String, Any)): system = {
    setProperty(kv._1,kv._2)
    this
  }

  def deepCopy = {
    val s = new system(id)
    getAllProperties.foreach(p => s.setProperty(p._1,p._2))
    s
  }

  def isIdenticalTo(s: system) = {
    hasSameId(s) && hasEqualProperties(s.getAllProperties)
  }
}

case class dataset(val uid: String = null) extends node with sealedManifest{
  val id = if (uid != null) uid else uuid
  override val manifest = immutable.HashMap(
                            "name" -> ("java.lang.String","req"),
                            "description" -> ("java.lang.String","opt")
                          )
  override def isComplete = true

  def <= (kv: (String, Any)): dataset = {
    setProperty(kv._1,kv._2)
    this
  }

  def deepCopy = {
    val d = new dataset(id)
    getAllProperties.foreach(p => d.setProperty(p._1,p._2))
    d
  }

  def isIdenticalTo(d: dataset) = {
    hasSameId(d) && hasEqualProperties(d.getAllProperties)
  }

}
```

The use case is ultimately that many additional classes like 'system' and 'dataset' will be generated.  I am seeing a lot of build up of boiler plate at this level notably in 'deepCopy' and 'isIdenticalTo'.  That smells wrong and I think that these blocks of code can be moved to higher levels in the class diagram, but I am struggling to achieve this.

When I try to move the code to higher levels I run into problems because these methods are identical in everything except type.  So I was hoping the type classes might help, or simply (multiple-)inheritance.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you should really capitalize your class names. it's pretty much a universal Scala standard. also we never use all-uppercase in Scala by convention

Comment: you probably want F-bounded types: http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#self-recursive-type